# imgur uploader error in Native Cascades BlackBerry 10

Tags: blackberry, qml, native, blackberry-10, imgur

I modified source code from gifhub imguruploader (https://github.com/thurask/imguruploader) but this error. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Stal.jpg

Anyone know how to make this work? Or otherwise, know of a another similar Javascript IMGUR uploader(client side)? I apologize for not being very adept with scripting?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Uploader::Uploader(QObject *parent): QObject(parent)
{
    m_apiKey = QLatin1String("Authorization: Client-ID 38c6928b0ee218a");
    m_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(m_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)),
            this, SLOT(requestFinished(QNetworkReply *)));
}

Comment: QNetworkReply * reply = m_manager->post(
                                QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.json")), 
                                requestBody);